# Custom Querysets using Multiple Models in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to findout a way in which i can use multiple models in a Queryset. For instance, in my case i have 2 tables - Photo and User.

```
class Photo(models.Model):
username = models.ForeignKey(User)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
alt_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class DR_User(models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User)
    follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followed_by', symmetrical=False, blank=True)
objects = DR_User_Manager()

class DR_User_Query_Set(QuerySet):
    def profile_pic(self):
        # uid = self.userid
        photo = Photo.objects.get(username=uid)
        if photo.exists():
            return photo.image.url
        else:
            return 'http://d12df125d01b8a258a3a-8112fdc02f7d385b44f56eb9e899d81c.r88.cf2.rackcdn.com/default.png'

    def userinfo(self):
        uid = self.userid
        obj = User.objects.get(id=uid)
        userinfo = obj.first_name + ' ' + obj.last_name
        return userinfo.title()

class DR_User_Manager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return DR_User_Query_Set(self.model)
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.get_query_set(), name)
```

my aim is to create a custom queryset for DR_User where i can get the userinfo from User Table(auth_user) and the image url from the Photo Table...so that when i use -

```
user = DR_user.objects.all()
```

i can access them at once using {{ user.profile_pic }} and {{ user.userinfo }} in my template.

Comment: Can't you just traverse the relationship?

Comment: forgive me if i am a noob but can you give me an example?

Comment: Let's say you get the user `user = User.objects.get(id=1)`. From this relationship you can go `user.photo_set.all()` to get all images.

Comment: this can be done in the view function yes for a specific user. But if i want the list of all user's their firstnames,lastnames and photos...how do you implement it in a for loop function in template?

Comment: Have you tried using `{% for %}`?

Answer (score 0):

Too much work.

```
class DR_User(models.Model):
   ...
  @property
  def profile_pic(self):
    try:
      return self.userid.image.url
    except models.DoesNotExist:
      return settings.DEFAULT_PROFILE_PIC_URL

  @property
  def userinfo(self):
    return unicode(self.userid)
```